# How to retrieve a chat msg with sender and receiver username in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

```
chat Table
-------------------------------------------------------
msg_id  msg(description of msg)   sender(id)   receiver(id)
-------------------------------------------------------
1       hello                      2             1
1       how are you                1             2
----------------------------------------------------------

user table
-----------------------
u_id   username
-----------------------
1       usman
2       Ali
---------------------
```

here you see two tables one is for chat and one table is for user
i make a relationship between these two table but i feel difficulty how to extract data from these table.

**what i want..**

i want to extract each sender msg with its username and each reciver name with its username like facebook chat so i make this query

i put this query in database

```
select u.user_name UserName,msg.msg
from user u,messages msg 
where (msg.sender or msg.receiver)=(select u_id from user where u_id= 1 )
    and msg.sender=1
order by msg.msg_id desc
```

but this query repeat sender message with receive name and receiver msg with sender name

i want to show sender and reciver msg show separably with their name tell me any method how i fix it.

Comment: Are you against using a JOIN? I am assuming when Ali goes to check for chat, you just want to see messages sent to him. `SELECT u.username AS UserName, c.msg FROM chat AS c JOIN user AS u ON c.sender = u.u_id WHERE c.receiver = 2 ORDER BY c.msg_id DESC;`

Comment: Mark's answer is to the point. But you may save 2 joins & extra headache. put username directly in sender & receiver column If the username is unique.

Comment: @Bsienn: maybe, but it's cheaper to store/compare integer IDs. a message table can very quickly become large, and even a few microseconds saved per query can add up to very large savings in the long run.

Comment: @MarcB you are right about INT ids, but i though joins might take extra time instead of natural keys. i'm no expert doe ^_^

Comment: username is only part of things. maybe a later query would want user email, or real name, which'd require a join anyways. blah blah blah. a properly normalized database would not store "repeated" data in a child table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have would never work. the `or` comparison will return a boolean true/false value, which you then compare against the value of `u_id`. And since that `u_id` query is hardcoded to return only  `1`, you're effectively doing `where true/false = 1`.

You need to join the `user` table twice (once for receiver, once for sender):

```
SELECT sender.user_name, receiver.user_name, msg.msg
FROM msg
LEFT JOIN user AS sender ON msg.sender_id = sender.u_id
LEFT JOIN user AS receiver ON msg.receiver_id = receiver.u_id
ORDER BY msg.msg_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  select users.name, messages.msg ....          Etc from messages inner join users on       msgs.userid = user.id where                             (sender = :sndr and receiver = :rcvr)         or (sender = :rcvr and receiver= :sndr)  order by date desc;        
                take note of the named parameters there.  That would return the conversation between the two users
```